# Why \n in python gives two blank lines?

Tags: python

I can't understand why \n gives two blank lines in the output. For example:

```
>>> def my_function():
    print("ABC")
    print("\n")
    print("DEF")


>>> my_function()
ABC
                      # First blank line
                      # Second blank line
DEF
>>>
```

Can anyone explain what happens here and how to fix it?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`print()` prints a newline at the end of its output by default.  `print("\n")` thus prints two newlines: the one in the `"\n"` string and the one at the end of the printing operation.

Answer (score 6):

Python adds a default newline when the print function is used
To print in python without a newline in python3 use

```
print("hello",end='')
```

Source: https://docs.python.org/3/whatsnew/3.0.html#print-is-a-function

Comment: +1

Just a note to the answerer: It's always good to point to official sources whenever possible. It allows readers to dig in deeper.

I've edited your answer to add the following source link:
Source: https://docs.python.org/3/whatsnew/3.0.html#print-is-a-function